# Some questions about jQuery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a program that will display a list of items. When someone clicks on an item, a popup will appear that will load in and displays more info about that item with the jQuery load function.

Both cases:

**case 1** - the program that loads in the more info is in the same document as the program that displays the list of all items.

**case 2** - the program that loads in the more info is in another document specially made for the more info call.

The questions I have are about bandwidth and loading speed.

The questions:

- does bandwidth grow faster in **case 1** ?
- is loading speed slower in **case 1** ?

The code I would use for the more info call:

- case 1 load function

  $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/main.html?GET_DATA=id #container" );
- case 2 load function

  $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/more_info.html?GET_DATA=id" );

Comment: Loading speed in terms of first page load, or loading the more info call?

Comment: @Kev Loading the more info call

Comment: I would suggest, create a template for more info in same HTMl page and either load data on click or if you have big JSON, load it async. Dont block bandwidth for data that will be used later during load

Comment: Case 1 loads the entire document, then puts the contents of #container into #result and discards the rest. jQuery operates on the client side, there is no mechanism to tell the server to parse the HTML document and send only parts of it.

Comment: definitely case 2 is better

Comment: @JJJ So i assume it take's longer to load in the content in case 1, because the function is also loading in the list of items as well and than discards them

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, case 1 is to preload all your More Info data with the initial page, and case 2 is to load it on demand.

Up to a certain number of items (depending on the environment), case 1 could have a quicker Load More Info action, because it avoids a round-trip with the server.  However, the initial bandwidth needed to load all of the info will increase with every item that might need to be shown.

In other words, case 1 does not scale.  It depends on your application as to whether this is important or not.  If you know in advance that the number of items will always be small, it might be an acceptable trade-off to preload all the items.

I would recommend getting data of the scale you expect to handle, and benchmarking it both ways.  Then you'll have an objective answer specific to your application--as far as your scale expectations can be trusted, at least.

Comment: No, in both cases you would load in the more info content on demand. But in case 1 the more info program is in the same document as the program for displaying the list of items.

example of case 1:
""CODE FOR DISPLAYING ITEM LIST""... if(isset($_GET['GET_DATA'])){""CODE FOR MORE INFO""}.... ""SCRIPT FOR MORE INFO CLICK EVENT""

Comment: @MarkoMihalič, when you say 'program' you seem to be talking about HTML data, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, HTML, PHP content.

Comment: OK so when you say 'is in the same document' you mean it's at the same URL, but PHP is giving a different document based on the parameter you send with the request (`GET_DATA=...`).  In that case it completely depends on your PHP code, but I would recommend case 2 just for cleanliness.